# Alternative to Instant Form Pro

Tags: php, forms, open-source

I was looking for a PHP form generator this morning and ran across "Instant Form Pro" by Joel Comm (http://www.instantformpro.com). It looks like it offers what I'm looking for (easy to use quick form generator based on PHP and MySQL that's self-hosted with no other fees), but the site smacks of "scam." It's being pitched as a way to generate surveys to increase your business, make lots more money, etc.

Is this thing worth the $97 or is there an open source alternative that might be... safer?

Answer (score 3):

[Wufoo](http://wufoo.com/) is a really famous form service. I have used it in the past and I was very happy with it. [Google Forms](https://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=87809) is also a pretty good solution, if you don't need to generate complex forms and if you don't have strict integration requirements.

There are several other alternatives if you search for [form generator](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=form%20generator).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [machform](http://www.appnitro.com). It is pretty much the same (PHP MySQL, self-hosted, no monthly fees). The price is way cheaper as well ($39).

Comment: I visited the site for MachForm and was surprised to see some similar graphics... Either Instant Form Pro is reselling MachForm or they are straight up stealing it! Thanks a ton, everyone!

Comment: There is a difference. The Instant Form Pro version can be installed on an unlimited number of domains while the MachForm version is $39 for one, $99 for 10, and $199 for unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

An old but still relevant question - PHP Form Builder is a complete alternative, including a [Drag and drop form builder](https://www.phpformbuilder.pro/drag-n-drop-form-builder/index.html) for non-coders. [Disclaimer: I'm the author]
The application is not totally free but available at an affordable price, and it comes with a complete documentation and a huge amount of capabilities with the integrate jQuery plugins (file uploader, text editor, live validation, date, time, color pickers, ...)

Comment: Do you have any association with your recommendation?   I would normally delete this outright because recommendations from new users tend to be self-promotion or spam.  However, you have a bit of reputation of StackOverflow, so there is a chance you are making this recommendation in good faith.

Comment: Yes, I'm the author, but the comment seemed relevant to me anyway. I just edited to specify that I'm the author of this form builder.

Comment: Thank you, we require that all affiliations with recommendations be disclosed.